# Does a ring of transposition prevent further action by the user?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, teleportation

The [ring of transposition](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-transposition) says (emphasis mine):

> Once per day, the wearer of the ring of transposition can speak a command word to exchange places with the creature wearing the bonded ring, which must be within 800 feet, **as though using a [dimension door](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dimension-door) spell** against a willing target.

One of the important drawbacks of dimension door is that it stuns the caster immediately upon arrival:

> After using this spell, you can’t take any other actions until your next turn.

Does the ring's wording mean that this effect is included, or does it only mimic the teleportation effect of dimension door?

Comment: I changed the title since "stun" is a specific thing (a Condition) with its own riders that don't apply to Dimension Door.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The user is unable to take further actions

When an effect says "as though", you apply **all text in the relevant spell/effect**. If it was intended that you could use it "as though using a dimension door spell" *except the user can still perform actions*, then it would be stated as such. This is further supported by the range of the teleportation effect being defined by the item, one of the few other reasons to reference a spell directly.

An example of such a reference is the spell [Cast Out](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Cast%20Out)

> Treat this as a targeted dispel magic spell, except cast out can dispel one such spell for every four caster levels you possess.